# How to prevent showing MC when his _y coordinate becomes to the -100?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a problem when one B.swf file is loaded to another A.swf file.

A.swf file size is 400x400.

B.swf file size is 100x100.

B file has a movie clip (MC) which is animated and position of this movie can be from Y:-100 to Y:200.

B file is loaded into the center (X:150, Y:150) of the A file.

When B file is loaded, then animation starts. I have a problem: I can see animated movie clip B out of B screen scope (for example: when B.swf file movie clip has _y = -100 I still can see that movie clip in A.swf). I am expecting that movie clip will not be shown if Y position becomes negative.

**Maybe someone has an advice how I could prevent B.swf file’s movie clip appearing on A.swf file?**

Cheers,
Ramunas

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mask to hide the parts that are not to be visible.

In your example, I guess the best way would be to let B have a 100x100 mask, that would mask out everything outside that area.